# Remove inline listener in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listener, inline

What is the proper way to remove inline click listener in react?

```
  var ClickComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return (<div onClick={this.onClickStuff} className="orange noselect">
       Click me {this.state.clicks || ''}
      </div>);
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
      return {
        clicks: 0
      };
    },
    onClickStuff: function (e) {
      this.setState({
        clicks: this.state.clicks + 1
      });
      if(10 < this.state.clicks){
        // remove listener
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-render your component without the `onClick` event:

`onClick={10 < this.state.clicks?undefined:this.onClickStuff}`

It looks like:

```
    var ClickComponent = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return (<div onClick={10 < this.state.clicks?undefined:this.onClickStuff} className="orange noselect">
            Click me {this.state.clicks || ''}
            </div>);
        },
        getInitialState: function () {
            return {
                clicks: 0
            };
        },
        onClickStuff: function (e) {
            this.setState({
                clicks: this.state.clicks + 1
            });
        }
    });
```